# 2x2 design (ANOVA): can i only look a 1 main effect and an interaction?

Tags: anova, interaction, lm, main-effects

I have a model: `lm(measurement ~ Status + Treatment + Status:Treatment, contrasts=list(Status = contr.sum, Treatment = contr.sum), data=data1) #contrasts to account for unbalanced design as I have been told to do`

I have applied this to an ANOVA type III.

Here is the question, relating to the biological query:
I am interested to know 1. if "Status" has an effect and 2. if "Status" and "Treatment" together affect the outcome. I am not actually interested to know if "Treatment" on its own has any effects. Would it be sensible to omit `Treatment` in the `lm` forumla, and if so, do I remove the `Treatment = contr.sum` (and/ or in fact the whole `contrasts` argument)?

When I run the above model, I get a signifincant effect in Treatment but when I run `lm(measurement ~ Status + Status:Treatment, contrasts=list(Status = contr.sum, Treatment = contr.sum), data=data1)`, I get a significant interaction Status x Treatment.

Would it be appropriate to just do the latter? I am not trying to go fishing, but this does address my biological question more appropriately, right?

Edit: typo

Comment: Do not fit the model without both main effects. If there is an interaction interpret it. In the light of that interpretation it may, or may not, be possible to look at main effects. The principle involved here is called marginality which might be a good search term on this site or more widely.

Comment: Note to close voters. I think there is a genuine statistical issue here not a programming one.

Comment: thank you @mdewey I've done a quick search on marginality and that definitely answers my question (and I will include both main effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this does not go unanswered I repeat here my original comment.

Do not fit the model without both main effects. If there is an interaction interpret it. In the light of that interpretation it may, or may not, be possible to look at main effects. The principle involved here is called marginality which might be a good search term on this site or more widely.